# window unload working for Firefox but not on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, event-handling, unload

Currently trying to run a function through the `window.addListener('unload')` event. This is the **code I am trying to run:**

```
window.addEventListener('unload', this.returnToDashboard)
```

**returnToDashboard():**

```
location.href = './'
```

The event gets triggered on Firefox but does not work on Chrome. My Chrome Version is: **Version 104.0.5112.79 (Official Build) (x86_64)**

Not sure why it is not working on Chrome. Any insight would be appreciated on alternatives. Thank you.

**Update:**

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event) docs I am supposed to be using `pagehide` event but that does not trigger for Chrome either.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (we don't know what `returnToDashboard` does) and the steps to reproduce the problem (we don't know how you are triggering the event and there can be differences between "click a link" and "close the browser tab").

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:jquery]? There's no sign of any use of that library in your question.

Comment: I have made changes according to your comments

Comment: Why are you trying to navigate to a different URL on `unload`? Either the viewport is going away (so there is nothing to navigate in) or the user has done something to navigate elsewhere (in which case it is either something like a bookmark (and none of your business to override) or its a link or form submission that you provided … so why did you provide it?)

Comment: The page I am trying to navigate from is an error page. Once an admin refreshes an error page, it should take them to the specified url. Thats just the behaviour I was asked to replicate.